# Function to return true if current page has child pages

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, function

I'm trying to create a simple function to do a "status test".  Goal is to test and see if the current page being viewed has any child pages or not.  Using this to alter layout to accomodate child pages.  The following code seems like it should work, but alas, no dice.

Anyone see what I'm missing? **EDIT**-  Note that this is in WordPress.

```
function is_subpage() {
global $post;                              // load details about this page

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {   // test to see if the page has a parent
    return true;                                            // return true, confirming there is a parent

} else {                                   // there is no parent so ...
    return false;                          // ... the answer to the question is false
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-query-posts-to-list-child-pages?replies=7

Comment: The problem with all the examples that I've found (and this one too) is that they assume I'm trying to get the $pageid of a static page.  What I really want to do is just test whether the current page has any children and then return true or false.

Comment: hmm... have you tried this
`<?php
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);?>
if( count( $children ) !== 0 ) { //true code }
else { //false code }
?>`

Comment: That's pretty much the only way I've been able to do it.

Comment: You could also use `<?php $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
if ($children) { //true code } else { //false code } ?>` (from http://wordpress.org/support/topic/if-has-child-pages-display-them-if-not-do-something-else)

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems a bit resources intensive to load all the child pages just to do a simple check, I thought of this early this morning:

```
function has_children($p = null) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    $pid = ($p) ? $p : $post->post_parent;

    if ($pid) :
        $r = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = $pid LIMIT 1");
        if ($r) : return true; endif;
    else :
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

You can use it just as if (has_children()) or pass it the post parent if (has_children($post-post_parent)) — the latter is helpful if you're using get_posts/get_pages and not the global $post variable.